# Merging multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

It looks like the `pandas.merge()` method is restricted to working with only two dataframes.

When I try to pass it multiple dataframes, e.g.

```
pd.merge([df1, df2, df3], on='some_column')
```

it doesn't work.  On the other hand, `pd.concat` does accept multiple dataframes, but it doesn't take the argument `on` to specify the columns on which to join.

Why was `merge` constrained to only work with two dataframes? Isn't joining multiple tables a common operation when working with relational data?

Comment: You can eg do `df1.merge(df2, on='some_column').merge(df3, on='some_column')`. Also in SQL you have to do multiple joins to join multiple tables.